# IOS: UIImage sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports

I have this code:

```
imageNumber++;
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]init];
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"l%d_s%d.png", currentSet, imageNumber]];
            [imageToColor setImage:image]; //<-- here it crash 
            [image release];
```

so, after a few minuted my app crash with this message

```
[UIImage isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

why?? can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
imageNumber++;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"l%d_s%d.png", currentSet, imageNumber]];
[imageToColor setImage:image];
```

The problem with your code is that you allocate a `UIImage` object on image variable and then without releasing it you set it to another autoreleased object. `[UIImage imageNamed:]` returns an autoreleased `UIImage` object.

Comment: ok, but what's the reason whereby my app crash after few minutes and not immediately, can you explain me?

Comment: autoreleased objects don't get released immediately

Answer (score 3):

You are allocating a new image, and then you are assigning that pointer to an autoreleased UIImage returned by `UIImage imageNamed:`, causing a memory leak, then you try to release an autoreleased object, which get released again, causing the error.

```
imageNumber++;
image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"l%d_s%d.png", currentSet, imageNumber]];
[imageToColor setImage:image]; //<-- here it crash
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you got it all wrong. At first you alloc-init object and then assign autorelased object to the pointer, making the first object leaking. Here is the correct code:

```
imageNumber++;
UIImage *image [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"l%d_s%d.png", currentSet, imageNumber]];
[imageToColor setImage:image];
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You don't need to allocate an empty image before loading the image from a file.

2) Are you sure that the image specified by the string [NSString stringWithFormat:@"l%d_s%d.png", currentSet, imageNumber] actually exists and is available to the app ?

the imageNamed call will return null if that image cannot be found. Step through in the debugger and see if the image is actually loaded.